# Cannot get WSS working with ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I followed: http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html

ActiveMQ opens the port but I cannot connect to it.  Nothing in the log other than its opening the port for it:

2014-07-14 23:49:19,775 | DEBUG | Publishing: wss://0.0.0.0:61617 for broker transport URI: wss://0.0.0.0:61617 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main

2014-07-14 23:49:20,170 | INFO  | Listening for connections at wss://data-util1:61617 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | main

Any ideas?

I am running activemq 5.9.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Thanks!

Jim